# Running 'mvn clean install' on Spring Boot application using env variables in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

Hello I am trying to package my Spring Boot app into a jar.
I want to deploy this app to AWS Beanstalk and so I will be injecting some variables into application.properties using Environment variables.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGODB_URI}
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
CLOUDINARY_URL=${CLOUDINARY_URL}
jwt-secret=${JWT_SECRET}
server.port=5000
```

However when I run the maven command (`mvn clean install`), during the package process the code is executed and it is failing stating that

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customBeansConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'CLOUDINARY_URL' in value "${CLOUDINARY_URL}"
```

I have a class `CustomBeansConfig`:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBeansConfig {

    @Value("${CLOUDINARY_URL}")
    private String cloudinaryUrl;

    @Bean
    public Cloudinary cloudinary(){
        System.out.println("cloudinaryUrl = " + cloudinaryUrl);
        return new Cloudinary(cloudinaryUrl);
    }
}
```

Please help me to create the jar file

Comment: @Value("${CLOUDINARY_URL}") is legit in your annotated component class, but the values in application.properties have to be literals, as far as I know. 
Have you tried reading from System.getenv("CLOUDINARY_URL") in your component? Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, one approach may be to use different application.properties files for different environments. For example application-dev.properties for the Dev environment and application-prod.properties for the Prod environment.  Then your CLOUDINARY_URL may be assigned different literal values appropriate to each.
Then when deploying to each environment, bundle your JAR with the -Denv option, as in

mvn -Denv=dev clean install

OR

mvn -Denv=prod clean install

... and upload the resulting JAR file to the corresponding AWS environment.

Comment: Hi. I have tried this but when I run 'mvn -Denv=prod clean install' during the build process the code is executed and during the execution it tries to use the properties in the 'application.properties' file such as spring.data.mongo.uri to connect to database but does not find a suitable uri as the value of this key is ${MONGO_URI} and thus fails. So how do I fix this ?

Comment: So you have a file application-prod.properties matching -Denv=prod? In the original application.properties, delete everything and put just one line:

spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties%

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Running the Spring Boot application with a such config property, got me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Circular placeholder reference 'CLOUDINARY_URL' in property definitions
```

Changing the name of your Spring property from `CLOUDINARY_URL` to, for example, `cloudinary.service.url` will resolve the issue.

In such case, your config file should look like this:

```js
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGODB_URI}
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
cloudinary.service.url=${CLOUDINARY_URL}
jwt-secret=${JWT_SECRET}
server.port=5000
```

And your configuration file like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomBeansConfig {

    @Value("${cloudinary.service.url}")
    private String cloudinaryUrl;

    @Bean
    public Cloudinary cloudinary(){
        System.out.println("cloudinaryUrl = " + cloudinaryUrl);
        return new Cloudinary(cloudinaryUrl);
    }
}
```

Also, I would advise you to avoid creating Spring configuration properties using the underscore format, since it usually used for the environment variables, maybe be confusing and may cause such interesting issues.